# Returning a Float in Graphene after querying DB

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I am using some example code to return a list of fields and all is working for my Data Models. However I want to take an input, query the db, do a calculation and return a single number back. Everything works, bar getting the output to the end user.

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
   growth = graphene.Float(id=graphene.String())
   def resolve_growth(self, info, id):
      records = list(Model.objects.filter(id=id).order_by('date'))
      ## do calculation
      return calculation
```

I get the following message in GraphiQL

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field \"growth\" of type \"Float\" must not have a sub selection.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 32
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am making the following query on the client side using graphiQL:

```
{growth(id: "AAN") }
```

but this gets morphed into by the front end:

```
{growth(id: "AAN") {
  id
} }
```

In the end I solved this by returning an Object.

Comment: query ...................

Comment: @xadm what do you mean??

Comment: what query / request gives this response?

Comment: @xadm I put in the original post

Comment: I see only resolver and response - both server side - where is the request (query) invoked on client ?

Comment: @xadm I edited for clarity. The query was run in graphiQL

Comment: growth - as float needs to be end-node/property, query should result (and be defined as) in object - one of property can be float or list of floats ... start with graphql types definition .. or explore graphiql docs if created ones are equal to expoected

Comment: I'm not following. This should be a simple query, just to respond say one number which for test purposes could be returned. I'm not sure why node needs to be used. I have not for lists of documents coming back from the DB.

Comment: `query SayHello {
      growth(id: "AAN")
    }`  - there is no `id` inside `growth` to be returned from resolver (you asked for in query), float can not have child